# Which IPA build is correct for App Store?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, ipa

I have noticed that there are 2 ways to create IPA for App store.

1- Create ***Runner.xcarchive*** file and then with Xcode export IPA file.

2- When you're creating ***Runner.xcarchive*** file, flutter creates an IPA for you as well(Flutter command: `flutter build ipa`). example:

```
project-app % flutter build ipa

 Building with sound null safety 

Archiving com.example.app.dev...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: *********
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        13.6s
Xcode archive done.                                         62.4s
Built /Users/user/StudioProjects/project/app/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.
Building App Store IPA...                                          20.8s
Built IPA to /Users/user/StudioProjects/project/app/build/ios/ipa.
To upload to the App Store either:
    1. Drag and drop the "build/ios/ipa/*.ipa" bundle into the Apple Transport macOS app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784
    2. Run "xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f build/ios/ipa/*.ipa --apiKey your_api_key --apiIssuer your_issuer_id".
       See "man altool" for details about how to authenticate with the App Store Connect API key.
```

If I use the IPA that Flutter provides in the second option, is it the same as the first way?